# creating sidebar in django using CSS but appears nothing

Tags: python, css, django

i was trying to create sidebar base on [codewithtim](https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/django/adding-a-sidebar/)

however it appears that it didn't read any of the css code

below is my
home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
    .sideenv a{
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: :    #818181;
    display: block;

    }

    </style>

    <title>{% block title %}home{% endblock %}</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="sidenav">

        <a href="">home</a>
        <a href="/vendor">vendor</a>
        <a href="/search">search</a>
        
    </div>


</body>

{% endblock %}
```

and here is my base.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>{% block title %}prototype{% endblock %}</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <!--{% include 'navbar.html' %}-->
    
    
    {% block content %}
    replace me 
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The only thing different from my code than codewithtime is i am trying to use block content to override some bolck.

it might be wrong  here, but i have no idea how to correct it

==================================================================

And i have another question about using css in django

when i google "css in django" usually the doc shows code below

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{%  static  'css/style.css'  %}">
    <title>Linguist</title>
  </head>
```

why did codewithtim can ignore the implementation and just include css

might be some stupid question

please help

Answer (score 1):

you misunderstood the way template blocks work. In your content you are dumping an entire html page, and you should only include the elements you want in that block. The base.html will be added by the **{% extends %}** call(which you also missed)

I would recommend you to read [though the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/) on the topic, before/while you try to manipulate tutorials. The templating engine is pretty powerful and it is good to get the idea how it works. That will allow you to plan your .html and views more efficiently.

the structure you are after is as follows:

- base.html -> contains the html head/body and declares the blocks. You got that correct

  - home.html -> extends the base.html and adds declarations for the blocks you want to override as shown below:

> ```
>     {% extends base.html %}     
>     {% block content %}
>       <div class="sidenav">
>         <a href="">home</a>
>         <a href="/vendor">vendor</a>
>         <a href="/search">search</a>         
>       </div>
>     {% endblock %}
> ```

I do not get where you are going with that include in the home base.html.

on your second question you can include the file directly, but since django serves the static files using it own sub-system it is recommended to do it as shown. This approach takes care for paths and whatnot and gives you more flexibility down the road.

Comment: thanks i understand a little but still can't get it   why my home.html can't read the css

Comment: do you refer to the " .sideenv a{" typo?

Comment: yes . and i try the static way still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution just change

```
<style type="text/css">
```

to `<style>`

then everything work well